# How to assign a tkinter Scale value to a variable in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

Here is the first cell of Jupyter Notebook which is a simple tkinter program.

Can I assign the scale value to the variable "a" and use it in the following cells of Jupyter Notebook?

Now the value of "a" I can get is always 0 in the following cells of Jupyter Notebook.

```
from tkinter import *
a = 0
def sel():
    selection = "Value = " + str(var.get())
    a = var.get()
    label.config(text = selection)

root = Tk()
var = DoubleVar()
scale = Scale( root, variable = var )
scale.pack(anchor=CENTER)

button = Button(root, text="Get Scale Value", command=sel)
button.pack(anchor=CENTER)

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()

#print(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a = var.get()`: Here `a` is a local variable within the function.

```py
a = 0
def sel():
    a = 2
    print("a from sel:", a)
sel()
print("a:", a)
```

Output:

```
a from sel: 2
a: 0
```

---

Alternatively, you can make `a` a global variable.

```py
from tkinter import *


global scale_value
# set default
scale_value = 0


def save_scale_value(event):
    global scale_value
    # save the current value while the program is running
    scale_value = event.widget.get()
    print(f"Saved: {scale_value}")

    
def sel():
    # reuse a variable in another function
    global scale_value
    print(f"global scale_value: {scale_value}")
    selection = "Value = " + str(var.get())
    label.config(text = selection)


root = Tk()
var = DoubleVar()

scale = Scale( root, variable = var )
scale.pack(anchor=CENTER)

button = Button(root, text="Get Scale Value", command=sel)
button.pack(anchor=CENTER)

label = Label(root)
label.pack()

scale.bind("<ButtonRelease>", save_scale_value)
root.mainloop()

# this will only print after the window is closed, when the root is destroyed
print(scale_value)
```

---

Also, you may not need an additional variable. You can use `var` after closing the window too.

```py
from tkinter import *

    
def sel():
    selection = "Value = " + str(var.get())
    label.config(text = selection)


root = Tk()
var = DoubleVar()

scale = Scale(root, variable = var)
scale.pack(anchor=CENTER)

button = Button(root, text="Get Scale Value", command=sel)
button.pack(anchor=CENTER)

label = Label(root)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()

# this will only print after the window is closed, when the root is destroyed
print(var.get())
# Later, you can assign the scale value to a variable in a cell.
# name = var.get()
```

Comment: Notes: [Using the LEGB Rule for Python Scope](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#using-the-legb-rule-for-python-scope), [The global Statement](https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/#the-global-statement).